# Accessing file in App_Data from a class in the App_Code folder

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.Net there is the app_data folder which is not accessible to users via the web. I would like to store a file in this folder, and read from this file by using a class that I have in the App_Code folder.

Keep in mind that the current working directory here is going to be a directory such as "c:\","c:\windows\system32\", etc. and not the application directory. So something like "../App_Data/somefile" does not work.

There has to be something simple that I overlooked on how to access files in the App_Data folder programatically

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access the App_Data folder like so:

```
string appdatafolder = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data");
```

I realise that this uses the HttpContext object, however, if you're writing this code inside a custom ASP.NET Membership provider (something I've done myself a number of times), you should have no problem using the HttpContext object.

Comment: Thanks, this got me off to the right start, I went for HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfilenamehere") approach as it seemed more readable.

Comment: @Brian - Glad you're up and running.  See this link, though, regarding performance of MapPath vs PhysicalApplicationPath:  http://dotnetperls.com/Content/PhysicalApplicationPath.aspx  May not be a problem if only accessing occasionally, but nice to be aware of the performance differences.

Answer (score 8):

You say you don't have access to context object but it's unclear why that would be.

If your code runs in response to a request then you can access the context as :-

```
HttpContext.Current
```

Failing that you can get to the root physical path for the application using:-

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

Comment: My class is in a data layer that has no references to the web and mvc libraries. Can this data class still use App_Data? HttpRuntime and HttpContext both make this persistence class aware of web deployment. Thanks

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Yes, although I think you actually answered your own question.

Comment: Not really, I just asked it poorly - more clearly, how can my repository class then write to the App_Data folder without referencing `System.Web` or any other web libraries? Are there other methods to pathing out to this folder?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Why would you not reference the System.Web.dll?  Its a standard component of the .NET library.

Comment: Separation of concerns. I prefer my data persistence services not know anything about the front end. For instance, I'd like to be able to yank these repository libraries out as a class library for reuse.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Then the best you can do is invent some interface through which your libaries aquire the folder path.  You would still need to write at least one implementation of this interface which has specific knowledge of being hosted in a website and you would still need supply an implementation of this interface to your repository code.  There is no super general builtin feature of .NET to acheive what you want.